# Assets: Uploaded File Doesn't Display in File Browser

Tags: assets, multi-site-manager, file-uploads, focus-lab-master-config

I'm running Assets 2.0.5 on EE 2.5.5 with MSM and FocusLab Master Config.

When I click "Upload", select a file from my computer, and click "OK", the Assets progress bar moves across the screen, but when it's complete the new file does not display in the file browser. The file is uploaded successfully, and is visible in the directory via FTP, it's just not visible in Assets. This happens both on the publish page and inside the Assets control panel.

Assets has been working fine on this site until about a week ago when this problem started happening. But the only changes I made around that time were to install Low Events and the URL Tube plugin; add a new channel and remove an old one. None of that should have affected Assets as far as I know.

I get a bunch of console warnings for each file that loads in the Assets browser:

[image]

I updated all the indexes but the problem persists. Please let me know what additional information you need to get to the bottom of this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try upgrading Assets to 2.1.1? Also, the first thing I'd check with this kind of error is to open the browser's debug console and look for JS errors.  Anything there?

Comment: Hi Lisa - I upgraded to 2.1.1 but the problem persists. There are no outright JS errors in the console, but there's a warning for every file: "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Comment: Kirsten, that's a bit odd.  Did you have your FTP client set to "auto" when updating Assets? And you did both the system/third_party folder and themes/third_party?  Could you add a screenshot of that error to your post please?

Comment: Lisa - I updated Assets using a Beanstalk deployment. I've added a description and screenshot of the warnings to my question. Please let me know if you need more info, thanks.

Comment: Any chance you'd share super admin and FTP information with me?  support@pixelandtonic.com if so. :)

Comment: Kristen emailed us that this is resolved. No known reason; permissions were reset to 777 and .htaccess cleared, but neither fixed it. Putting .htaccess back also didn't fix it; but after a few minutes, this started working. Kristen, to me it sounds like some aggressive server-side or browser caching. You might find out what caching your host uses in case you run afoul of this again. But for now - we don't have a "real" answer; but it is working. :) -Lisa, P&T